# Using React-Select purely as a drop down and appending selections as strings to a text field

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to be able to use react-select purely as a dropdown for autocomplete suggestions and once a user clicks on an option, it just appends the value of the option to a input field as raw text. The input field is just regular text. Is this possible with react select? I tried doing a custom value container but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have implemented it as per your understanding.

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");

  const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
  ]


  <Select options={options}
    onChange={setSelectedOption}

  />
  <input type="text" value={selectedOption.value} />
```